# Dropdown menu distorted on mobile device (Google Nexus 5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a design where its running fine when tested on PC.

But when I am viewing the page on mobile device (selected Google Nexus 5 from Chrome Developer tools) the dropdown is coming fine, but the menu list is not fitting the width.

In PC, I chose to use chosen jQuery library for dropdowns.

Here's my script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/chosen-dropdown-plugin/chosen.css">
<script src="../assets/chosen-dropdown-plugin/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{      
     if(!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) 
     {
        $('#campaign_list').chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"});
        $('#campaign_list_chosen').css({'width':'100%',
                                        'height':'30px',
                                        'border-radius':'2px'});
      }
      $('#campaign_list').css({'width':'100%',
                               'height':'30px',
                               'border-radius':'2px'});
}); 
</script>
```

So, the dropdown gets chosen enabled when viewed in PC, but not in mobile device. That part works fine. But in mobile device the menu is getting distorted.

Here's a snapshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide a demo fiddle.

Comment: demo fiddle will be a problem bro... cause the code includes lot of additional files... so quite impossible to manage all of them in fiddle

Comment: so if you can provide a link then also it's better to check.

Comment: bro can't provide the link.. its a company project and it runs only based on setting provided by him... and only available to our company domain  :(

Comment: ok tell me exactly what you want `java script` or `css`

Comment: Setting width = 100% means it will fill the width of the parent container. You have not shared enough information for us to solve this problem. We need the HTML, and the CSS of the relevant code causing your problem, specifically the element you're having a problem with and the parent container as a context. You have shared only the Javascript.

Comment: @amit, if you can provide javascript, then it will be better.

Answer (score 1):

You can set width depends on device or desktop with below `java script` code:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};

if(isMobile.any()){
    console.log("Mobile!");

   // set width for dropdown for mobile

} else {
    console.log("Desktop!");

    // set width for dropdown for Desktop
}
```

OR Use Css

```
#campaign_list {
position:absolute; 
left:10px; 
right:10px; 
margin:auto; 
width:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: its quite fine, but my problem is not regarding the dropdown, its regarding the width of the menu or list that is opened when we click on the dropdown.. :(

Comment: ok try below css for that dropdown 

`#campaign_list {position:absolute; left:10px; right:10px; margin:auto; width:auto;}`

`left:10px; right:10px;` adds spaces from left & right by 10px .

Comment: if `width` is inheriting from anywhere so add this css `width:auto !important;`